# StreamedResponse no descarga el archivo en el servidor

Tags: php, laravel

En mi app se genera un archivo txt con varios datos. Todo esto lo hace bien y en local se genera correctamente y se descarga.

Pero en producción el archivo se genera y se muestra en la pantalla, no se descarga.

Por que puede pasar esto.

Este es mi codigo:

```
foreach($reportes as $reporte){
            $content='';
            $content.= $reporte->documento.'|';
            $content.= $reporte->tipo_documento . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->bienes . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->ncf . '|';
            $content.=  "\r\n";
            print($content); 
            $content=''; 
    }

    // Se crea la respuesta para el txt
    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    // Se genera la respuesta con el contenido
    $response->setCallBack(function () use($content) {
        print($content);
    });
    // Se crean los datos del documento
    $disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 
    'DGII_F_606_'.$reporte->rnc_cedula.'_'.$tiempo->format('yym').'.txt');
    // Se descarga el archivo txt
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);
    return $response;
```

Comment: ¿Será que para producción, el navegador está aplicando una regla diferente? Algún popup bloqueado, algo?

Comment: @Alfabravo lo tengo exactamente igual en ambos sitios. Y podría jurar que antes funcionaba.

Comment: Revisa la consola del navegador, revisa la pestaña network y revisa a ver si sale la descarga de ese archivo, si da algún error HTTP o algo. Del lado del servidor, hay algún error en los logs de PHP? Si funcionaba antes es porque ALGO cambió y no se controló el cambio.

Comment: @Alfabravo Lo hice y veo el archivo y no muestra ningún error. Simplemente muestra en pantalla los datos del archivo.

Comment: Se está yendo con unos headers que hacen que el navegador lo pinte, o el navegador decidió que la app por defecto para abrir los txt es él mismo. No hay mucho más

Comment: Probé en varias computadoras con diferentes navegadores y hace lo mismo.